# should I include .vs folder in the .gitingore file?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I am working on a mvc core application. and files in .vs folder kept giving me problems. I have to merge files in .vs folder every time I checked in.  Is it safe to add it in the gitignore file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.vs folder to source control in visual studio 2015?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31526899/vs-folder-to-source-control-in-visual-studio-2015)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can add `.vs` folder to `.gitignore` - in fact you should do this on the beginning.

Also - when you create new repository on GitHub - you can use predefined `.gitignore` file... in your case it can be 'Visual Studio' (included `.vs` and a lot more):

[image]

For myself I always add additional lines to ignore Bower and NPM packages - they are automatically restored, so I see no reason to keep them in Repository (and this is really a lot of files) - unless you want to keep history of changes in these libraries - but that's your choice:

```
# Lib's
**/wwwroot/lib
node_modules/
```

BTW:
`.vs` is Visual Studio 'working' folder and is not required for storing solution/project - you can delete it when VS is shutdown and after that VS will recreated it during lunching any solution - of course you loose your working configuration of IDE, but no worries, it's not painful.

Comment: Look here: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore#L25-L26