# There is no .hgignore file after I do an initial hginit command

Tags: mercurial, hgignore

I've created my very first Mercurial repo on my machine. I used the hg init command on the directory.

Now I'm trying to use this ignore file, before uploading to BitBucket:

[Mercurial .hgignore for Visual Studio 2008 projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784/mercurial-hgignore-for-visual-studio-2008-projects)

Where would I post Even Mien's configuration file? I can't find an hgignore file anywhere.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make one in the top-level directory of the repository (the same place where the .hg folder is).

Comment: Windows says I cannot create a file without a name. What do I name it?

Comment: Windows is dumb about filenames that begins with periods, because it thinks the entire name is an extension. Use a text editor and in the Save dialogue put the filename as `".hginore"` (including quotes).

Comment: Also note that the `.hgignore` *will* be added to the repo (it's a tracked file like any other), but it still should not have any extension - just `.hgignore`.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new text file named .hgignore at the root folder of your project and paste the content into it.

Comment: What extension type? A simple .txt?

Comment: If I use a .txt file, it's not working. In fact, it tries to save the text file into the repo itself! :D

Comment: How can I save something with no extension? I'm using Windows 7. If I hide extensions, I can't remove the extension. If I show it, I can't remove it because it takes the '.' as the beginning of the extension.

Comment: check here for more details http://mercurial.selenic.com/bts/issue1315 .. I am happy I am not using windows thats for sure..

Comment: orhere http://kiln.stackexchange.com/questions/1230/how-can-i-create-hgignore-file-on-window-7